# C# Form flickering on simultaneous move

Tags: c#

I have build 2 forms. When the first one moves, the second one moves as well.
All works well except if I move the first form, the second form flickers during the move.
If I move the second one, the first form flickers during the move...

I'm using something like this...

```
    private void moveParentWindow(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (canMove == true) {
            if (frmM != null) {
                frmM.setShouldMove(false);
                frmM.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
                frmM.Location = Location;
                frmM.Left = Location.X - 10 - frmM.Width;
                frmM.setShouldMove(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Each form contains a setter/variable "canMove". The function is triggered by the move event of the form, and it moves the second form, and triggers the move event of the second form, which triggers the move event of the first form. It created a loop of events what was not working very well. This is solved by using a variable to control each others event triggering. Now, it works well but it doesn't solve my flickering issue.

Somehow it looks like some repainting is happening on the other screen during the move.

Does anyone have a fix for this.

Thanks.

Comment: That is not flicker, although it resembles it.  Set the Location property only once (i.e. don't assign Left as well) so the window doesn't jump back-and-forth.  So frmM.Location = new Point(this.Location.X - 10 - frmM.Width, this.Location.Y)

Comment: @Hans Passant: Thanks for your feedback. The issue is solved. Again, many thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of Hans Passant works very well!
By setting the location only once, the issue was fixed!

```
frmM.Location = new Point(this.Location.X - 10 - frmM.Width, this.Location.Y);
```